# Persisting objects after AJAX calls in Node.js

Tags: node.js

How can objects that are created during an AJAX request persist so that it can be used by subsequent AJAX calls?

I have tried using the debugger to see if my variables exist after a call to my route function and they seemed to be destroyed each time after the call ends.

Any suggestions or examples?

Comment: It will be easier to assist if you could show your code

Comment: There are numerous methods of [persistence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_(computer_science)) available. Which to use depends on your needs and the sensitivity of the information -- [Cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie), [Sessions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_(computer_science)), [Cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)), [Databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database), etc. Some are specific to web apps; others work well for any application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of [global variables are bad](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/06/01/global-domination/). I think what you are looking for is called [sessions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_%28computer_science%29). Using web framework [express](http://expressjs.com/) this is achieved without any pain.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "hello-world",
  "description": "hello world test app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.x"
  }
}
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser('keyboard cat'));
app.use(express.cookieSession());

app.get('/count', function (req, res) {
    if (req.session.count === undefined) {
        req.session.count = 1;        
    } else {
        req.session.count += 1;
    }

    res.send('Number of times you visited this page: ' + req.session.count);
});

app.get('/reset', function (req, res) {
    req.session = null;

    res.send('session has been reset');
});

app.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Listening on port 3000');
```

After you have created the file `package.json` you can install *express* issuing `npm install`. Then running program is as simple as `node app.js`. The route `htttp://localhost:3000/counter` counts how many times you have visited that page. *Even after you have shutdown server*. The route `http://localhost:3000/reset` is used to reset the counter.

Comment: Another question, how would I store different session variables for different connections? For example, every user has a different `req.session.foo`.

Comment: Those sessions are unique for every webbrowser you have running. I believe that is the desired behaviour. So they(req.session.foo) are unique for every user(browser).

Answer (score -1):

What I was looking for was the `global` object.

To use `foo` between different modules and router calls, I declared `global.foo` and used that object.

http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html

Comment: Are you looking for some kind of session storage?